# When does a pointer to a member variable become valid?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following class structure:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int test) : _test(test) { /* do nothing */ }
private:
    int _test;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A* a) : _a(a) { /* do nothing */ }
private:
    A* _a;
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    C() : B(&a), a(5) { /* do nothing */ }
private:
    A a;
};
```

I call the constructor to `B` with the address to `C`'s member variable `a` before I initialize `a`. As such, any accesses to `B::*_a` would be undefined until after I initialize `a`. However, is it also undefined behavior to even set `B::_a` to `&a` before the initialization of `a`? I.e., is the memory for `C::a` allocated as soon as the constructor is called, or only when the `a(5)` instruction of the constructor is called?

Comment: Just storing the pointer is ok. Dereferencing it is not, until the member is initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer itself becomes valid at the beginning of the constructor. You are allowed to obtain it, and store for future reference. Your code is perfectly valid.

It would be undefined behavior for B or A's constructors to dereference the pointer to "a", though, before the variable has been initialized.